# MySQL + MAMP port issue

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am attempting to use my local computer (running `OS X 10.10`) as my development server.
I setup `MAMP Pro` to use the default ports for `Apache (80)` and `MySQL (3306)`.

Whenever I open up `phpMyAdmin` it **does not** list the same databases as when I connect to the server from the command line `(using --port=3306)` and I cannot figure out where the error lies...

Comment: what is the command you are using to connect from command line,, i hope the user configured for phpMyAdmin and the one you are using are same.. have you checked the privileges for the user.

Comment: n00b mistake, sorry. I was using the wrong mysql (not the one that comes with MAMP) mysql --port=8889 -u root -p

Comment: I hope you are good now and connecting to the right port and getting the same databases via both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing two different instances of MySQL, running on two different ports.  Change either phpMyAdmin to connect to the one running on 3306, or else connect via the command line to the one phpMyAdmin is connected to.  Check your configuration in phpMyAdmin to determine the correct port.